# Unsure why program similar to bubble-sort is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, checksum, bubble-sort

I have been working on a programming challenge, [problem here](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/bubble-in-array), which basically states:

> Given integer array, you are to iterate through all pairs of neighbor
>   elements, starting from beginning - and swap members of each pair
>   where first element is greater than second.

And then return the amount of swaps made and the checksum of the final answer. My program seemingly does both the sorting and the checksum according to how it wants. But my final answer is off for everything but the test input they gave.

So: `1 4 3 2 6 5 -1`
Results in the correct output: `3 5242536` with my program.

But something like:

```
2 96 7439 92999 240 70748 3 842 74 706 4 86 7 463 1871 7963 904 327 6268 20955 92662 278 57 8 5912 724 70916 13 388 1 697 99666 6924 2 100 186 37504 1 27631 59556 33041 87 9 45276 -1
```

Results in: `39 1291223` when the correct answer is `39 3485793`.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
# Python 2.7

def check_sum(data):
    data = [str(x) for x in str(data)[::]]
    numbers = len(data)
    result = 0

    for number in range(numbers):
        result += int(data[number])
        result *= 113
        result %= 10000007

    return(str(result))

def bubble_in_array(data):
    numbers = data[:-1]
    numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
    swap_count = 0

    for x in range(len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[x] > numbers[x+1]:
            temp = numbers[x+1]
            numbers[x+1] = numbers[x]
            numbers[x] = temp
            swap_count += 1

    raw_number = int(''.join([str(x) for x in numbers]))
    print('%s %s') % (str(swap_count), check_sum(raw_number))
bubble_in_array(raw_input().split())
```

Does anyone have any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are slicing off the last element of the list in `numbers = data[:-1]`

Comment: @Shashank That is on purpose, on the challenge input they specify that the end of the input is signified with a "-1" which should not be included into the input.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the intention is to read elements until one element is `-1`. However, please remove all input stuff from your question if you have verified that this works. Replace it with hard-coded values that demonstrate the problem instead. Also, why use the old Python 2??/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your way of calculating  `Checksum`. It fails when the array has numbers with more than one digit. For example:

```
2 96 7439 92999 240 70748 3 842 74 706 4 86 7 463 1871 7963 904 327 6268 20955 92662 278 57 8 5912 724 70916 13 388 1 697 99666 6924 2 100 186 37504 1 27631 59556 33041 87 9 45276 -1
```

You are calculating `Checksum` for `2967439240707483842747064867463187179639043276268209559266227857859127247091613388169792999692421001863750412763159556330418794527699666`
 digit by digit while you should calculate the `Checksum` of `[2, 96, 7439, 240, 70748, 3, 842, 74, 706, 4, 86, 7, 463, 1871, 7963, 904, 327, 6268, 20955, 92662, 278, 57, 8, 5912, 724, 70916, 13, 388, 1, 697, 92999, 6924, 2, 100, 186, 37504, 1, 27631, 59556, 33041, 87, 9, 45276, 99666]`

**The fix:**

```
# Python 2.7

def check_sum(data):
    result = 0

    for number in data:
        result += number
        result *= 113
        result %= 10000007

    return(result)

def bubble_in_array(data):
    numbers = [int(x) for x in data[:-1]]
    swap_count = 0

    for x in xrange(len(numbers)-1):
        if numbers[x] > numbers[x+1]:
            numbers[x+1], numbers[x] = numbers[x], numbers[x+1]
            swap_count += 1

    print('%d %d') % (swap_count, check_sum(numbers))

bubble_in_array(raw_input().split())
```

**More notes**:

- To swap two variables in Python, you dont need to use a `temp` variable, just use `a,b = b,a`.
- In python 2.X, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Comment: I couldn't have hoped for a better answer. Thank you, that clears up my confusion and I learned some stuff I wasn't even expecting.